# Network issues with Broadcom 43438 Chipset (WSDB-104GN(BT))

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, broadcom

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Tablet PC with an Intel Atom Processor and knew this will cause problems.

I can't use WiFi because there is no option for it and I cannot find my WiFi card in the terminal with: 
`lshw -class network` nothing is showing up with this command.

dmesg | grep -i sdio has no Output too.

And I can't find any drivers for it.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't appear in the list of Broadcom devices supported by the kernel driver https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43